# Exception JavaBeans set datasource?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am new to *JasperReports*.

1. I am trying to create a javabean datasource, for that i already create a factory class

   ```
   ClassName : DataMapping
   Static Method : getBeanCollection() which contains list of bean.
   ```
2. Then I add my corresponding jar in that classpath also.
3. When I click test in "JavaBean set datasource" window I am getting exception like:

   ```
   General Problem:
   com.policy.controller.DataMapping.getBeanCollection().
   ```

Can anyone assist me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

In the class name and the static Method fully qualified path of the class should be given for instance

**ClassName**: *com.policy.controller.Datamapping*

**Static Method**: *com.policy.controller.DataMapping.getBeanCollection()*

Before setting the Java Bean datasource you need to set the jar file in the classpath as this will cause error if class is not found.

Hope that this helps

Please check the whole process here http://javabeansinjasper.blogspot.in/ 
and identify the point where you are going wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it is working for me, instead of adding jar file i added direct classes folder to dataset. But with the jar file it is giving the same error. I believe this is because of some tempDate/AppData. is there any way that i can clear temp data for ireport?And One More doubt.
How does template is getting mapped with the dataset?